# fine prime factors but i have to only distinct answers in the list

Tags: python, distinct, factors

I'm trying to make a **list** of prime factors for any number  but i only want **distinct** numbers so i don't was to have for number 8 ( 2,2,2) I just want to get [ 2]
but I'm not sure how

```
     def primes(n):
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac.append(d)  
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
       primfac.append(n)
    return primfac
print(primes(18))
```

Comment: Convert your list to a set then you don't get repeated values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime that you have multiple values you can take the set of them. If you want a list you can convert it back to a list:

```py
list(set([2, 2, 2]))
```

The whole function now looks like:

```py
def primes(n):
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            n //= d
            primfac.append(d)
        else:
            d += 1
    if n > 1:
        primfac.append(n)
    return list(set(primfac))
```

Comment: I was just messing around with a few things and copy-pasted it back, I agree that it should remain unchanged except for the last line for clarity